# Examples of combinatorial proof of inequalities? (Proof by injection, proof by surjection)

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, inequality

It's commonplace in combinatorics to prove $A = B$ by describing a bijection between sets of size $A$ and $B$.

What are some examples of proving $A < B$ by describing an injection between sets of size $A$ and $B$, or of proving $A > B$ by describing a surjection?

Here's [an example of what I'm looking for](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/506636/proving-an-inequality-involving-integer-partitions). Ideally, I'd like some examples that are very elementary (so I can teach them to students without background in a particular area).

Comment: Probably too simple, let $B$ be the power set of $A$, map $a$ to $\{a\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Many bounds on binomial coefficients can be proven this way.

For instance, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/95178/133281) answer provides such a proof of the inequality $\binom{2n}{n+1} \geq 2^n$.